ROS turtlesim reporting turtle image spawn
ROS Melodic used at least 14 turtle images in turtle_frame https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/melodic-devel/turtlesim/src/turtle_frame.cpp, is it possible to have ROS report which image is used in spawning a new turtle?
